# Comparing two ranges of numbers performantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

I'm creating some parallax scrolling code (I know, I know), and I've got running smoothly, but I've run into a snag with an advanced use-case. [Here's a demo](http://livemercury.com/demos/parallaxissue/).

It's now a buttery smooth 60fps in Chrome, Safari & FF, and that's partly because I'm only updating positions of elements when they're in view. I check for this using this code (found in [main.js](http://livemercury.com/demos/parallaxissue/main.js) of said demo):

```
a = obj.offset + obj.height - winScroll,
b = winHeight - (obj.offset - winScroll);
if ( (a <= winHeight && a >= 0) || (b <= winHeight && b >= 0) ) {
```

Basically, I'm checking if the object is in view like this:

[image]

If a **or** b are greater than 0 but less than the height of the window, then it's visible.

This works great for things that are smaller than the window, but what about things that are larger? Basically, what I have to do is take a range of numbers (all the pixels between the top of the window and the top of the window + it's height) and compare it to another range of numbers (the offset of the object and the offset of the object + it's height) and see if any are the same numbers.

How do I do this in the already crowded 16ms I have every frame?

Comment: You could introduce an index and order the elements by it. Look for the lowest and highest visible indexes and everything in between is visible, the rest aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to prove (A) is to disprove (¬A).

First, assume the object and the window are rectangles each with 4 properties (`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`) that represent values in the coordinate system.

And assume that the origin `O(0,0)` is the top-left corner of the window, the positive x-axis extending to the right and the positive y-axis extending downwards with respect to the origin.

The object is **invisible** if and only if **at least one** of the following statements is true:

- `obj.left   >= window.right`
- `obj.right  <= window.left`
- `obj.top    >= window.bottom`
- `obj.bottom <= window.top`

Chain these in an `or` statement, and negate the result of that boolean expression.